# Finding the minimum number of specimens that must be tested

Tags: combinatorics

"Jen requests processing of a large set of clinical specimens. In a set of 2000, she would like the following to occur - 1700 specimens tested for CT, 1900 for NG, 1600 for Trichomonas and 1350 for GBS. What is the minimum number of specimens that must be undergoing testing for all four of these pathogens?"

Now, through trial and error, I have more or less come to the conclusion that the answer is 950 (or 550). But I have no idea how to go about this in a systematic way or how to verify my answer easily. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can say it this way:

Out of $2000$ specimens:

$1700$ were tested for CT, so $300$ were not.

$1900$ were tested for NG, so $100$ were not.

$1600$ were tested for Trichomonas, so $400$ were not.

$1350$ were tested for GBs, so $650$ were not.

It follows that the number of specimens not tested for at least one pathogen is the sum of these numbers : to see why, any such specimen must be counted at least once in the above list, and could be counted more than once, if it were not tested for $2$ out of the $4$ pathogens, for example (one very clean specimen,then). So the specimens not tested were at most $300+200+400+650=1450$. It follows that at least $2000-1450=550$ species were tested for all the four pathogens above.

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting way of looking at it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.